# java for each infinite loop - displaying entire list infinitely

Tags: methods, iteration, infinite-loop, display

So I'm probably missing a glaring error here, but I can't seem to figure it out. I have a menu that a user can use to display the entire inventory of a store. However, when I call the method that iterates through the inventory list, it displays the entire list infinitely. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyStore 
{
private Scanner kbd;
private int inventorySize;
private ArrayList<InventoryItem> list;

public MyStore()
{

    kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("What is the size of the inventory you are creating?");
    inventorySize = kbd.nextInt();
    list = new ArrayList<InventoryItem>(inventorySize);
    initInventory();
}

public void initInventory() 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < this.inventorySize; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Please select one of the following options: G)uitar D)rums");
        String input = kbd.next();
        String n;
        int nis;
        double p;

        if (input.equals("G"))
        {
            System.out.print("What is the name of this item?");
            n = kbd.next();
            System.out.print("How many items are you adding?");
            nis = kbd.nextInt();
            System.out.print("What is the price of this item?");
            p = kbd.nextDouble();

            Guitar guitar = new Guitar(n, nis, p);
            list.add(guitar);

        }
        else if(input.equals("D"))
        {
            System.out.print("What is the name of this item?");
            n = kbd.next();
            System.out.print("How many items are you adding?");
            nis = kbd.nextInt();
            System.out.print("What is the price of this item?");
            p = kbd.nextDouble();

            Drums drums = new Drums(n, nis, p);
            list.add(drums);
        }
    }
}

public void start()
{
    String nm;
    boolean done = false;
    while (!done)
    {
        System.out.print("Please select from the following menu:\n 1: Search for an item by name. \n 2: Display Inventory. \n 3: Quit \n ->");
        int menuNum = kbd.nextInt();
        int count = 0;
        while(count != 3)
        {
            if (menuNum == 1)
            {
                System.out.print("Please enter the name of the item: ");
                nm = kbd.next();
                searchAndDisplay(nm);
                count = 0;
            }
            else if (menuNum == 2)
            {
                displayWholeInventory();
            }

        }

    }

}

public void searchAndDisplay(String name)
{
    search(name);
    boolean found = false;
    if (name.equals(search(name)))
    {

        found = true;
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.print("Sorry, we currently don't have that in stock.");
    }
}

public InventoryItem search(String name)
{
    for (InventoryItem item : list.)
    {
        if (item.name().contains(name))
        {
            return item;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public void displayWholeInventory()
{
    for (InventoryItem item : list)   //loops through array and calls each item's print method
    {
        System.out.println();
        item.display();
    }
}

public void buyItem(String name)  //extra credit
{
    //find item, reduce numberInStock, print message for user
    //or if numberInStock is already 0, print suitable message
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    MyStore store = new MyStore();
    store.start();
}
}
```

And then here is my InventoryItem class, which has the original display method:

```
public class InventoryItem 
{
private String name;
private int numberInStock;

//Constructor
public InventoryItem(String n, int nis)
{
    name = n;
    numberInStock = nis;
}

//display the item
public void display()
{
    System.out.print("Item Name: " + name + " Stock Number: " + numberInStock);
}

//return name
public String name()
{
    return name;
}
}
```

The displayWholeInventory() method is where the iteration happens, sorry for the rest of the code, that's still a work in progress.

Any help would be appreciated, even if it's just a push in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: I see only two places where `count` is modified. In both places it's set to zero.

Comment: `while(count != 3)` - when would `count` ever become 3?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I figured it out. I adjusted the code here:

```
public void start()
{
    String nm;
    int count = 0;
    while (count == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("Please select from the following menu:\n 1: Search for an item by name. \n 2: Display Inventory. \n 3: Quit \n ->");
        int menuNum = kbd.nextInt();

        if (menuNum == 1)
        {
            System.out.print("Please enter the name of the item: ");
            nm = kbd.next();
            searchAndDisplay(nm);
        }
        else if (menuNum == 2)
        {
            displayWholeInventory();
            System.out.println();
        }
        else if (menuNum == 3)
        {
            System.out.println("Goodbye.");
            count = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I had one too many loops inside.